# uitextfield hide by keboard animation not properly work with orientation change...?

Tags: iphone, animation, keyboard, orientation

when user tap on uitextfiel, I just animate view to up so, keyboard not hid that field.
it work properly but in between that if I rotate device it not work properly.

my view code is as below

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown));
}
-(void)textFieldShouldReturn:(id) sender
{
[sender resignFirstResponder];
}
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
[self animateTextField:textField up:YES];
}
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
[self animateTextField:textField up:NO];
}
-(void)animateTextField:(UITextField*)textField up:(BOOL)up
{
const int movementDistance = -130;
const float movementDuration = 0.3f;

int movement = (up ? movementDistance : -movementDistance);

[UIView beginAnimations: @"animateTextField" context: nil];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: movementDuration];
self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, movement);
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

when I tap on textfield, check below

[image]

[image]

In this keyboard up position I just rotate my device, check below

[image]

when I tap on return on keyboard, check below

[image]

you can see, the issue

Thanks

Comment: Are you rotating your device all the way around, to portrait upside down?

Comment: Yes, as I describe in image 3

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);




[textfield resign first responder];
}
```

whatever u use like the function
just add

```
[textfield resign first responder];
```

Comment: Thanks, but as you can find in my question, I already did this thing...!?!